# Process array list from map

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, objectmapper

We are trying to access the array of object that placed inside a map.

Can any one guide us to get **length** of the array as well as fetching each element from the list. Sample map object given bellow.

```
{
    storeId = 1,
    ShipToStreetLine1 = test 123,
    ShipToCity = Seattle,
    OrderDetails = [{
        distributor_name = SS,
        product_name = HORN 80897 AM GUN 300BO 125 HP 50/10
    }]
}
```

We need to get the **size** of `orderDetails` array and if data present, then I want to fetch `product_name`.

Comment: You need to deserialize it to some Object

Comment: Btw is this the content of a Java map? If yes, what is its type? Is it `Map<String, Object>`?

Comment: Could you please show us the full code of your object? It's not easy to give you precise method instructions if we only have this *model*. (see [mcve])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

Create a POJO which is type of what you are getting in orderDetails

Like

```
public class OrderDetailElement{
    private String distributor_name;
    private String product_name;
    public String getDistributor_name() {
        return distributor_name;
    }
    public void setDistributor_name(String distributor_name) {
        this.distributor_name = distributor_name;
    }
    public String getProduct_name() {
        return product_name;
    }
    public void setProduct_name(String product_name) {
        this.product_name = product_name;
    }

}
```

in your logic class you can do is

```
    ArrayList<OrderDetailElement> orderDetails = yourMap.get("OrderDetails");
    List<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (orderDetails.size() > 0) {
        for (OrderDetailElement orderDetailElement : orderDetails) {
            products.add(orderDetailElement.getProduct_name());
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Suresh : if this solves your problem please accept the answer. It will help with my reputation. Thanks a lot